# How to set nowrap property to td element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I tried:

```
function(nowrap)  {  
 var cell = $(`'<td>'`);  
 //cell.wrap = wrap (not working)   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna get a particular `td` from table and set its property, then try it.

First give a unique class name or id to its `td`.

Using the ID, write

```
$('#td1").attr("nowrap","nowrap");
```

Using the class, write

```
$('.td1").attr("nowrap","nowrap");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [nowrap attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_nowrap.asp),

> `<td nowrap="nowrap">`

Using css this should work with div element, not sure about td

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
> .nowrap {
>   white-space: nowrap;
> }
> </style>
>
> <div class="nowrap">Content here</div>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $cell = $('td');  
$cell.css("white-space", "nowrap");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` function. also check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp). It says that `NOWRAP` is deprecated. Instead use `CSS`

```
<script>
$(function() {        
       var cell = $('<td></td>').attr({'NOWRAP': 'NOWRAP'}).appendTo('.tr').html('asdfsd');  
});
</script>

<table>
    <tr class='tr'><tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";

or

td.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
```